# Why there is a huge difference between GC.GetTotalMemory() and CLR Profiler numbers?

Tags: c#, memory, object, size, profiler

I have an object that I need to cache several of it for a web app in IIS so I am analyzing how much memory each instance use.

I wrote a small `exe` and I call `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` before and after construction and the difference is around 335k but if analyze it in `CLR profiler` it shows me **22 MB** of memory is used for the object which does not make sense.

What am I interpreting incorrectly in CLR profiler ?
Where should I check in profiler to see individual object sizes ?

Comment: CLR Profile is worth what you paid for it.  Don't waste your time on it, unless your time is free as well.

Comment: Did you only make one instance? What if you make multiple instances? I guess (but it's a wild guess) that the 22MB will stay stable until you have made enough instances to fill it all up (so after 65 objects or so it might jump to 44Mb)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN: The garbage collector does not guarantee that all inaccessible memory is collected.

[look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx)

CLR profiler shows all the memory allocated;

What if you use  GC.GetTotalMemory(false) what is the result?